# TypeScript import doesn't work after compiling to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export, es6-modules

### starting-page.ts

```
export function startingPage () {...rest of function}
```

### main.ts

```
import { startingPage } from "./starting-page";

startingPage();
```

### index.html

```
<script src="/dist/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### Error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module                         main.js:1
```

### Description

I suppose it does not work because in JS files it should be ***module.exports = startingPage;*** as it is in my previous vanilla JS projects and it works just fine, however it is TS project and I have no idea how to make it work. **edit:** obviosuly, I am then importing it as ***const startingPage = requrie('...')***

Comment: What are you using to compile the typescript?

Comment: I am running tsc command, although I might have found a solution to my problem but I certainly need a confirmation on that one. 

On the other project I am using a Parcel for project build, is it possible that my problem here is that, I am using a node-side 'require' on the page-side script, without using webpack (which I think Parcel involves)? EDIT: I also removed module: 'commonjs' from ts.config as I am targeting es6, not es5 as by default

Comment: I am really new to all of these so I apologize if I am making it more difficult to understand

Comment: Parcel used Babel not webpack

Comment: You need `type="module"` added to your `<script>` tag

Comment: @evolutionxbox that is true, however they both are considered as solution to my problem.

Comment: @VLAZ I have tried it before, it then returns an error: `main.js:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/dist/starting-page net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 2):

Solution to my problem was installing a Parcel - application bundler.

As I mentioned I used it in my vanilla JS projects, so I tried it also now, and it is working just fine. It was more of a JS syntax error than TS project build problem.

Comment: Glad you found a solution